# mobile phones make/model/characteristic database

Tags: database, mobile-phones

Please help finding software/database with mobile phones make/model/characteristic database. I need it to integrate into my website.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Most of these are copyrighted so we can't help you. Best idea is to pull the data manually from the makes you know....

There might be free sources out there, but I highly doubt it.

*edit*

to update my post... Wikipedia is a great source of information, but please observe the licenses which they have over their data. Most often, it's the Creative Commons License, but this doesn't meant that their sources have other licenses... And there are others too...

Manufacturers/Makes:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mobile_phone_makers_by_country
http://www.phonearena.com/

Models:
http://www.phonearena.com/

Comment: If you are not going to provide a solution to the question do not post, he did not ask whether or not it was copyrighted.  He asked where he can find a list of all mobile devices, I don't see how copyright comes into place when it is public information?